# Access variable inside the tab page of the Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabpage

Here I'm facing problem,I'm adding form dynamically into tab page.
I have to get a static variable from that form.

i used code,but i can't get exact value which  i need.

```
 private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TabPage page in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            Control control = page.Controls[0];
            if(!hyber.Form1.receiverflag)//bug line
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(page);

            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

In the above pic watch window

page.controls[0]
->[hyber.form1]
-->receiverflag

how to get that variable value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show how the variable receiverflag is declared exactly inside your Form1 class?

Comment: public static bool receiverflag; on the pic u can see it clearly its static member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are nor clear about bug line or in saying can't get the exact value you need.

if the variable is a `public static bool` it belongs to the class and not to the instance, being static, so when you write:

```
hyber.Form1.receiverflag
```

you are taking the variable's value regardless of the specific instance of Form1 you are dealing with, does not matter at all if you have created one instance and added to the TabPage, that variable always exists even if you do not create any instance.

if you are getting wrong/unexpected results could be, eventually, that another thread or another method has changed the value of that static field and this reflects everywhere in your application.

**Edit:** if it was not static, you could probably get what you are asking in this way:

```
var yourForm1 = (page.Controls[0] as hyber.Form1);

if( yourForm1 != null && !yourForm1.receiverflag)
{
  ....
```

Comment: obviuously you right so only i setting seperate instance to every tabpage , i need to access by path i mentioned page.controls[0] ->[hyber.form1] -->receiverflag how to do that

Comment: so every tab page is separate instance of the hyber.Form1 and static variable belongs to that tab page only ,so another static variable won't reflect.

Comment: you do not need to access by path because it is declared for the class, remove the static keyword in declaration and then you can access by path.

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'hyber.Form1.receiverflag .so its not possible if i do like that.